# Webcam's focal length as mm

Tags: opencv, camera, webcam, dimensions, calibration

I calibrated my webcam using OpenCV documentation. This calibration gave me that results at 640x480 pixel: fx= 793 px and fy = 793 px. With an object I placed at a certain distance from the camera, I verified the results using the Triangle Similarity Theorem. I am almost sure the fx and fy values are correct. But they are pixel values. I need the true value of focal length as mm. How can I learn it?

I did some research. I can find the focal length(mm) by multiplying the size of the pixel on the sensor by the focal length(pixel). But I don't know the pixel size on my sensor. How can I find out?

Here are my calibration results:

```yaml
%YAML:1.0
---
K: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 3
   cols: 3
   dt: d

   data: [ 7.9316410969554488e+02, 0., 3.2760305913561973e+02, 0.,
       7.9295276367223937e+02, 2.3887445842489257e+02, 0., 0., 1. ]

D: !!opencv-matrix
   rows: 1
   cols: 5
   dt: d

   data: [ -1.4639629863258644e-01, 2.9530406678197738e+00,
       6.3927306862592514e-04, 6.0115438385712828e-04,
       -1.5184138772323958e+01 ]
```

Here is my webcam(it is the cheapest webcam, there is not a brand):

[image: My webcam]

I can disassemble the webcam case and look inside of webcam. Is there any information about the focal length or sensor size?

Comment: in the pinhole camera model, you don't really have a focal "length". your number 793 relates the field of view (49° in your case, tan((640/2) / 793) * 2 * 180/pi) to the scale (640 pixels) on the image plane. I would advise against disassembling it because that can introduce dust to the sensor that you'd have to clean. the focal distance numbers you know from photography are not directly translatable to digital cameras, mostly because the image plane is at a different distance and the sensor/image has a different size.

Comment: little mistake in my calculation: it's 44° even, it's the arctan